# 2000 subaru forester 2.5l

Tags: subaru, forester

I have a plastic lid that fell off a five inch hole on my engine block right under my airbox dont know whats that lid is or should it be sealed? Also I'm throwing a p0440 code ... and my biggest issue is a rattling wobbling sound coming from the front of my motor but the noise is tricky ... it seems to be near my cam shaft pulley? It's been getting worse also since I replaced my alternator? Could it be that lid making that noise considering I had to sit it back over the hole it was made to cover? I'm wondering if it was once sealed over the hole?any help is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Some visual reference of what the "five inch hole" is you're talking about would go a long way.

Comment: Do you have a photo? I know the Forester 2.5 engine of that year pretty well, but I can't think of any 5" 'holes' that need a lid?

Comment: Pulleys go bad more often than you think, especially after changing the tension on an alternator belt - don't plan on any long trips until you figure that out.  The code (upvoted below) can also be a magical spider that crawls up a fuel vent line and makes a cocoon like web that blocks proper vapor movement. *(Still check rust, disconnected tubes, gas cap, etc. There are some steel lines near the trunk/tank that are Uber expensive to replace)

Answer (score 0):

P0440 basically means your fuel tank or related hoses and piping have a leak somewhere. The simplest solution is to check that the gas cap is on correctly; if you live in the rust zone, also check to see if the fuel filler neck to the gas tank has not rusted through.